# Bash - create JSON string dynamically and add as argument

Tags: bash

I have a shell script with 3 Parameters:

```
#!/bin/bash

VHOST=$1
EXCHANGE=$2
DELAY=$3

RABBIT_CMD="docker exec rabbit rabbitmqadmin -u rabbit -p rabbit --vhost=$VHOST"
COMPLEX_CMD="$RABBIT_CMD declare queue name=${EXCHANGE}-delay"
COMPLEX_CMD="$COMPLEX_CMD arguments="

COMPLEX_CMD="${COMPLEX_CMD}'{\"x-message-ttl\":$DELAY,\"x-dead-letter-exchange\":\"$EXCHANGE\", \"x-dead-letter-routing-key\":\"worker\"}'"
echo $COMPLEX_CMD
$COMPLEX_CMD
```

Now I call this script

```
./script.sh rdb blah 5000
```

The second last line `echo $COMPLEX_CMD` outputs the following line:

```
docker exec rabbit rabbitmqadmin -u rabbit -p rabbit --vhost=rdb declare queue name=blah-delay arguments='{"x-message-ttl":5000,"x-dead-letter-exchange":"blah","x-dead-letter-routing-key":"worker"}'
```

When I copy-paste this into my bash and execute it, it works without any problems. But when I want to execute this in the script (last line `$COMPLEX_CMD`), I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not parse JSON:
  '{"x-message-ttl":5000,"x-dead-letter-exchange":"blah","x-dead-letter-routing-key":"worker"}'
```

How do I have to escape my strings within the JSON in the right manner?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does shell ignore quotes in arguments passed to it through variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136948/why-does-shell-ignore-quotes-in-arguments-passed-to-it-through-variables)

Answer (score -1):

Found the solution: Just put `eval` before the `$COMPLEX_CMD`, so change the last line to

```
eval $COMPLEX_CMD
```

Comment: You are just pushing the piece of soap to the corner of the pool where the shark is sleeping.